# Microsoft Office Plugin Enabled/Disabled Indicator?

Tags: buttons, toggle, conventions, plugins

I want to design a plugin (addin) for Microsoft Office, where I want people to use it while writing emails via Outlook. Also, I want to use my brand colors (flexible, not a major constraint). 
The problem I am facing is,
1. How to make people use it more? (Stand out and CTA should be that it is not being used currently but do you want to use it?)
2. If it is being used then how to inform/indicate that this is active and currently being used in your email?

I want to make this plugin look more native but stand out somehow also the one who is using it should be able to figure out if this is implemented on his/her email.

The plugin contains a button for using/not-using it and 3-4 check boxes for if they are using this plugin then what all features are being used. I might have an option of expanding this menu of 3-4 checkbox items if I am using this plugin and minimizing these 3-4 checkboxes if I am not using it.

i. Minimize space taken by this plugin when I am not using it.
ii. Should be able to identify if the plugin is implemented on email or no, by any means like color change or something similar. (open for possibilities)

Edit 1 :
My Plugin will help a user to customize the signature for every email. Idea is to keep it somewhere in the ribbon, occupying less space but visible. Once I click on the button, the options should be visible for what all I have to customize but if I don't use it I should have an option not to use it and should be clear to a user that what exactly it means (Enabled/Disabled) [image: Wireframes for the Email Signature Customization Addin]

Comment: What does your plugin (addin) actually do? Do you have any wireframes or user flows we could comment on? At the moment the question just asks us to design the plugin for you.

Comment: @locationunknown : Thanks for asking this, sorry I missed elaborating the plugin purpose earlier. Please check the Edit 1 above.